# Is there a more direct way to achieve this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have an inheritance like this:

```
class Parent {
  some_object_property = ["some_object_property_depending_on_initialization"];
  constructor() {...}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  some_object_property = [...super.some_object_property, 'child_property']
}
```

Is there a way to let the `Child` inherit and extend object property `some_object_property` from the `Parent`?

I know I can achieve the end result through `getter` and `setter`. Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Do you mean a static property, as in `Parent.some_object_property`?

Comment: What do you mean by more direct way? If you instantiate a Child here, then `new Child().some_object_property` should just be "some_object_property"

Comment: I'm confused by the question. In this case Child will have `some_object_property`... what's the issue?

Comment: @tadman No, static property is on the class, but this is meant to be on each objects.

Comment: @jmkmay yes but it can only be accessed though `Child.__proto__.constructor.some_object_property`. Kind of long.

Comment: Please show your actual code, and how you are using the two classes - where you call `Child`, and how you expect to access `some_object_property` (including an explanation why you need to access it there). The code you've shown does not have any reason to use inheritance at all. Also it's unclear what code you refer to by "using getters and setters".

Comment: What do you mean with extend object property? You can do this adding in the constructor of Child super(); and after this this.some_object_property have that value.

Comment: @Bergi, I've edited my post. running it now produce an error saying super is not an identifier recognizable.

Comment: Well wow that's a totally different question now! But yes, you cannot use `super` in a class field initialiser. Either put that line inside the constructor where it belongs, or just use the `this` keyword instead - it's just as good, no need to use `super` here, `this.some_object_property` will refer to the instance property that was initialised by the parent constructor before you're overwriting it with a new value.

Comment: @Bergi How can I adopt your comment as answer?

Comment: @北美38fule I made it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It produces an error saying "super is not an identifier recognizable".

Yes, you cannot use super in a class field initialiser. Either put that line inside the constructor where it belongs (like in @DannyEbbers' answer), or just use the `this` keyword instead - it's just as good, no need to use `super` here:

```
class Parent {
  some_object_property = ["some_object_property_depending_on_initialization"];
}

class Child extends Parent {
  some_object_property = [...this.some_object_property, 'child_property']
}
```

`this.some_object_property` will refer to the instance property that was initialised by the parent constructor before you're overwriting it with a new value - it runs as if written inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.someProp = ['someprop test', 'something else'];
  }
}



class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {  
    super();
    this.someProp = [...this.someProp ,'added child prop'];  
  }
}

let myChild = new Child();

console.log(myChild.someProp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. But I actually mean a property that can vary depending on different initialization. Please review my post, I just edited it to make it a little clearer.

Comment: I assume this works for u, different initialization could be passed trough arguments the constructor() and the super().

Or based on what different initialisation.

As long as it's not static and bound to this. its bound to the instance of the class, and not the class.